# MS Chart Export to PDF

Tags: c#, export, mschart

I am working on Business Intelligence of my company but when i export my graph to PDF it is empty not showing the values on PDF.I search about my problem on this platform but my problem not solved.
[image: Lets Suppose i want to export this graph on Pdf but when i export it on PDF it not ![out put like this no graph and values shows]showing the graph and as well as the values i also upload PDF image ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCAQf.png)
Here is my code.

```
  btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Response.OutputStream);

    Doc.Open();

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        Chart1.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(memoryStream.GetBuffer());

        img.ScalePercent(75f);

        Doc.Add(img);

        Doc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=XYZ_BI Chart.pdf");

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        Response.Write(Doc);

        Response.End();

    }
}
```

Comment: no one can answer where the all champ

Answer (score -1):

Install a CutePDF printer, so that when you print your document it will create a PDF of your Chart, no coding required.

Sample code for printing (VB.NET)

```
MyFooChart.Printing.Print(True)
```